# Force divs to display side by side and hide any overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, carousel

I am trying to create a simple carousel which starts with item 1 and can slide along to the last item (does not need to be an infinite chain of items).

I am having some trouble with displaying the items in a row, however:

```css
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.carousel {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.carousel div {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

([Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/617zpoy9/))

When the page is resized, my inner div items squash together and appear on top of each other, even though I have `overflow-x: hidden` set on both `.carousel` and `html` in the css.

What I would like to happen is if the page is resized (or if the carousel items slide along) the items should stay side-by-side and just overflow off the screen out of view.

Can someone please tell me if this is possible and point me in the right direction?

---

After some more experimentation, I set `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` to hidden in `.carousel` as well as set the `border-box` and `white-space` properties.

I set the inner `divs` to `display: inline-block` and `margin: auto`.

Now I should be able to get `.carousel` to slide left and right using jQuery, and the images will stay in a line.

```css
.carousel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
}

.carousel div {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel" class="carousel">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/617zpoy9/5/)

Comment: How about I just give you a working slider I made a while back? http://jsfiddle.net/c9dhn9nc/36/

Comment: Thanks! this should help me work out how to add the animations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check my css and discern it by yourself.
I hope it helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/617zpoy9/2/

```
<style>
  .carousel {
    height: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: red;
  }

  .carousel div {
    background:blue;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
<div class="carousel">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ^^^ his answer is far more correct, I am going to put mine into the comments instead :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try some javascript code to define the width of ".carousel", but you can try this...

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.carousel {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left:  0px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 10000px;
    background: blue;
}

.carousel div{
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to set a width to your divs different to 100%:

https://jsfiddle.net/617zpoy9/4/

Like so:

```
.carousel {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left:  0px;
    top: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    width:9999px;
    background: blue;
}
```